# How to use arbitrary property names in a JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm working with JSON data where one portion of it is a key-value pair collection, where the key is an arbitrary string and the value is an array of strings.  I'm trying to write a schema for this, but I'm not sure how to represent arbitrary property names.  So for an object like this:

```
{
  "K1": ["V1", "V2", "V3"],
  "K2": ["V4", "V5"],
  "K3": ["V6", "V7"]
}
```

What would be the right way to write a JSON schema with the following requirements:

- There must be at least one property.
- Properties can have any arbitrary string for their name
- Every property's associated value must be an array of strings
- Every string array must contain at least one string (ie. must not be empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express a restricted pattern for a property or set of properties with `patternProperties`; its value is a schema, which is evaluated against the values of all properties that match. So for example, to express a set of rules used for properties that start with a capital letter, you can do `"patternProperties": { "^[A-Z]": { ... more rules here ...`. To define the rules for a property name in terms of a full schema, you can use `propertyNames`.

To express a schema for the value of all properties, regardless of name, you can use `additionalProperties`. These rules will not match against any property already matched with a `properties` or `patternProperties`.

You can express the minimum number of properties with `minProperties`.

You can express the rules for all items in an array with `items`. And `minItems` can be used to express the minimum allowable number of items.

The schema for your data can be expressed by:

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "minProperties": 1,
  "additionalProperties": {
    "type": "array",
    "minItems": 1,
    "items": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html